# Makefile rebuilds all objects when only one source changes

Tags: c, makefile

I use a Makefile to compile a C project, it works as expected exept for a part: when i change one thing in one source file, the whole thing gets rebuild. I'm pretty sure the problem is there :

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    @echo -n 'Compiling $@ ... '
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(patsubst obj/%.o, src/%.c, $@) -o $@
```

But, i clearly specified a single file as the dependency, the currently-being-build file. How can this be a problem ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Does it print `Compiling filename.c ...` for each file? Also, does it do this even if you don't change anything?

Comment: Yes it does. for every object file

Comment: Does it rebuild every file even if you don't change anything?

Comment: Nope, if nothing changes, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

regarding this code in the make file:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    @echo -n 'Compiling $@ ... '
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(patsubst obj/%.o, src/%.c, $@) -o $@
```

This will create all the *.o files

What you really want is:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    @echo -n 'Compiling $@ ... '
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Why will the first one create all .o files, and why won't the second one, assuming that OBJ_DIR=obj and SRC_DIR=src?

Comment: a simplistic explanation: the first one expands the `$(patsubst...) to be a list of all the *.c file names converted to *.o file names and each of those *,o file names need to be generated  For more details, run make with the `-d` parameter.  (this will output a huge amount of information, and buried within that information is the expansion of the `patsubst`.

Comment: That is incorrect - notice that the substitution happens to $@, which is **not** "a list of all the .c file names"

Comment: @immibis,  I did say it was a 'simplistic explanation'  I know full well that my comment was not the full story, I also know the second rule works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

All right i solved this, this was a stupid one.

SRC_DIR was defined as :

```
SRC_DIR = src
```

With a space at the end ... removed it, worked instantly. My bad...